# couchbase SELECT QUERY Syn

Tags: nosql, couchbase

I have inserted a user document. when I run the SELECT query: `SELECT * FROM my_buckt WHERE type = “user”`

I can see the result as shown below.

```
[{
    "my_buckt": {
        "createdTs": xxxxx,
        "createdBy": "xxxx",
        "data": {
            "title": test
        },
        "type": "user",
        "uuid": "xxxxxxxxx"
    }
}]
```

But when i try to run the below query, it is giving an error. I just added the type after the bucket name. Please advise what I’m missing in order to make it work for the below SELECT query:

```
SELECT * FROM my_buckt user WHERE type = “user”
```

> “code”: 3000, “msg”: “syntax error - at user”,

Comment: What the param "user" means? You don't have assign the type when you SELECT from database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `user` is a reserved word (See [documentation](https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/reservedwords.html) for a full list of reserved words). So either you can use something else as the alias, like so:

```
SELECT * FROM my_buckt u WHERE type = "user"
```

or you can put backticks around user, like so:

```
SELECT * FROM my_buckt `user` WHERE type = "user"
```